# In what context can pullbacks be interpreted as the dot product betwen vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry

**Context / intuition**

I'll use Picard theorem to state the reasoning behind the question. The question itself is not related to this theorem.

In $\mathbb R^2$ with coordinates $(x,u)$.

Consider $\theta=du-f(x,u)dx$ such that $f(x,u)=du/dx$.

Consider curves $c:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ such that the pullbacks $c^*\theta=0$ and $c^*dx\neq0$ are valid.

Then (according to Picard), there exist a one-to-one correspondence between solutions of $du/dx=f(x,u)$ and the curves $c$.

I make the following observations:

1. Saying that a vector field $\theta$ is always normal to a curve $c$ is equivalent to saying that the dot product of the line tangent to the curve against the vector field is always zero. Now, $\theta$ looks exactly like the normal vector to a solutions of $f(x,u)=du/dx$, and in this case $c^*\theta=0$ would look like the corresponding vector product that should always be null.
2. Through the same reasoning, stating that $c^*dx\neq0$ is always (at least in a certain domain) would mean that the curve $c$ is *never* precisely perpendicular to the constant vector field $dx$.

So interpreting these pullbacks as dot products between the tangents of curve $c$ and the $\theta$ and $dx$ vector spaces, all existing in $\mathbb R^2$, makes sense in this setting/context.

Now, in a general setting/context (no longer Picard), I know pullbacks of differential forms by functions (each defined over some crazy due manifold) can have different intuitive interpretations.

**The question**

In a general setting/context what does it take for such pullbacks to actually correspond to dot products and, furthermore, is there any special relation between pullbacks and dot products?

Comment: I would say no, because the point of this formulation is to work with differential forms and thus *avoid* dot products.

Comment: I absolutely agree. The whole idea, though, is to try and get an intuition: understand in what context do pullbacks and dot products match and then get a feel to how pullbacks eventually diverge from dot products.

Comment: $\theta$ is a 1-form, not a vector field! It also doesn’t make sense to say $f(x,u) = du/dx$.

Comment: @TedShifrin a closed 1-form can, for instant, be interpreted as the gradient of a scalar field. That's what I meant. Maybe should have said covector field instead? Also, the equality you pointed out is meant to be a general 1st order ODE (linear or not in $u$). Is it wrong?